# Colour rows of an entire sheet based on values in a column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a Excel file of daily expenses, with each row containing records of a single transaction.

Consider the following:

A: Date of transaction
B: Received/Spent
C: Payer/Payee
D: Details
E: Amount

The `B` column can have entries of these types:

1. Spent by Cash
2. Spent from Wallet
3. Spent by Check

(and similarly for Received)

I want to colour the columns A-E by Red or Green, according as the transaction is Spent or Received.

I can detect whether a particular cell contains a particular word or not, using `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(word, cell))`, how to use conditional formatting on a particular based on this.

But I do not know how to apply this to the entire sheet, except the top row.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try Conditional Formatting

Comment: @Mikku I said in the question that I can do it to a row, but don't know how to apply it to all the rows.

Comment: Select all the data and then apply the formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

- Select all data
- Goto Conditional Formatting
- Select New Rule
- Enter the Formula as per Screenshot.
- Repeat for other Keywords.

[image]

Use this formula to get all the Spent in One go : `=ISERROR(FIND("Spent",$B2))=FALSE`

[image]

Comment: I recommend to use two rules `=SEARCH("Spent",$B2)` and `=SEARCH("Received",$B2)` on range `=$A$2:$E$6`. No need to catch errors or use `ISNUMBER`

Comment: Thanks, it does the job. Is there a way to use something like `if-else if-else` here? Say, I like to colour as red, if cell contains "A", blue if "B", green if "C". Then do I have to create 3 rules? Or, can it be done in one rule?

Comment: Would be less complicated if you create 3 rules. Just copy and change the existing one. Because anyway you won't be able to change color even if you are able to apply the condition. With different rules you can select different colors with different condition and same Range.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have it working for one row you have the necessary formula - just adjust the `Applies to` range.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. using the `$` in your formula is key to color from A-E, whether or not you adjust the range. The outcome would be very different.